# Cursor For Loop with dynamic SQL-Statement

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, database-cursor

Is there a way to perform a Cursor For Loop with an dynamic SQL-statement?

If I don't want to declare a record I can do something like this (only if I declared the cursor..):

```
For I in cuSelect Loop
  dbms_output.put_line(I.NAME);
End Loop;
```

And I can open a cursor for a dynamic SQL-statement:

```
Open cuSelect For 'Select * From TAB_X';
Fetch ceSelect Into recSelect;
Close cuSelect;
```

But to do that I have to first declare the Record.

Now my problem is that I have to open the Cursor for a very big and complicated dynamic SQL-statement. The structure of the record is unknown. Is there a way to open a variable cursor and iterate through it with an "undeclared" record?

Answer (score 8):

I think you can do what you want with DBMS_SQL package.

You can also check these:

- [Using Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm)
- [COLUMN_VALUE Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i1025449)

For example:

```
declare
  TYPE curtype IS REF CURSOR;
  src_cur      curtype;
  curid        NUMBER;
  namevar  VARCHAR2(50);
  numvar   NUMBER;
  datevar  DATE;
  desctab  DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  colcnt   NUMBER;
  dsql varchar2(1000) := 'select card_no from card_table where rownum = 1';
begin
  OPEN src_cur FOR dsql;

  -- Switch from native dynamic SQL to DBMS_SQL package.
  curid := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(src_cur);
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(curid, colcnt, desctab);

  -- Define columns.
  FOR i IN 1 .. colcnt LOOP
    IF desctab(i).col_type = 2 THEN
      DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, i, numvar);
    ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = 12 THEN
      DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, i, datevar);
    ELSE
      DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, i, namevar, 50);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  -- Fetch rows with DBMS_SQL package.
  WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(curid) > 0 LOOP
    FOR i IN 1 .. colcnt LOOP
      IF (desctab(i).col_type = 1) THEN
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, i, namevar);
        dbms_output.put_line(namevar);
      ELSIF (desctab(i).col_type = 2) THEN
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, i, numvar);
        dbms_output.put_line(numvar);
      ELSIF (desctab(i).col_type = 12) THEN
        DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, i, datevar);
        dbms_output.put_line(datevar);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(curid);

end;
```