# Dynamic Variable in Cursor in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

Need help in passing dynamic variable (table name) in cursor in Oracle stored procedure.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ABCDEF
    (TBL_NAME IN VARCHAR)
IS 

CURSOR CUR IS SELECT * FROM TABLEA 

BEGIN

FOR rec
IN CUR
LOOP
.
.
.
END
```

I NEED THIS TABLEA in cursor to be replaced by TBL_NAME variable. I tried to make the cursor statement as executable statement but it didn't help me.

Suggestions, please

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786953/cursor-for-loop-with-dynamic-sql-statement Also See: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:5045785413478::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1288401763279

Comment: partially same but the solution still doesn't work for the procedure example above

Comment: Typically: `sql_text varchar2;cur sys_refcursor; begin
   open cur for sql_text;
end;`

Answer (score 1):

```
Made this working using part of the solution above. Thanks for the suggestions. 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ABCDEF
(
   TBL_NAME IN VARCHAR
) IS 

TYPE curtype IS REF CURSOR;
cur curtype;
column1 number;
column2 number;

cursor sql := 'Select * from ' ||tbl_name;

Begin
open cur for cursor_sql;
fetch cur into column1,column2;

loop
.
.
.
close cur;
End
```

Comment: Applaud the self effort in taking the hints and apply them.